# express.js to GET json file in terminal

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, express

How do I GET a JSON file with express.js?  I want to be able to access it in my Mac terminal. I'm working on a college assignment that asks me to write an HTTP server that will act as a simple data store. It must respond to GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE requests. I must use express.js instead of fs for this app.

So far, in my root directory I have a server.js file and I have a subdirectory called lib that holds another subdirectory called notes.  Notes is where the JSON files will live.

In my root directory, I have a server.js file.  This is all I have so far:

```
'use strict'
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var notes = './lib/notes';

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //
  //this is the part I need help with
  //
}

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port ' + port;
});
```

Once I have this GET request working, from my Mac terminal I should be able to send a GET request and receive all JSON files inside the notes directory.

Comment: Does your notes folder contain the .json files? `I must use express.js instead of fs for this app.` What do you mean by fs? the `fs` module?

Comment: Correct.  I meant the fs module.

Comment: Can your notes be stored somewhere else such as a database or the web? Because, using `fs` is the only way to read data from your hard drive.

Comment: We can't use a database.  But Express allows us to use a `res.send()` function if we need the server to respond with data.

Comment: Yes... and also `res.json`. Anyway, in that case, you can use `res.sendFile(notes  +'file.json');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...from my Mac terminal I should be able to send a GET request and
>   receive all JSON files inside the notes directory.

Provided you do not want to use `fs` module(well you dont need one either),

you can simply set a route for GET requests and send the json file in response with `app.sendFile()`

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.normalize(__dirname + '/foo.json'))  
   //assuming your app.js and json file are at same level. 
   //You may change this to 'lib/notes/foo.json' to fit you case
})
```

`path` is a module that you would need to `require()`.

`__dirname` is the directory that the currently executing script is in.

and finally **foo.json** is the file containing your json

```
{
    "name":"nalin",
    "origin":"stackoverflow"
}
```

Here's the complete code for **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app  = express();


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.normalize(__dirname + '/foo.json'))
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Which will help you run the node server with `node app.js`.

Finally you can access the json with by

- visiting `http://localhost:3000/` on your browser
- by running `curl` command on your mac terminal `curl  localhost:3000`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve your .json files as static:

```
app.use('/notes', express.static( notes ));
```

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Or you can do it manually width path pattern:

```
app.get('/notes/:file', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(notes + "/" + req.params.file, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
     res.status(404).send('Not found');
    } else {
      res.contentType(req.params.file);
      res.send(data);
    }   
    res.end();
  }); 
});
```